# How to use enviroment variables in head tag @ index.html vite app

Tags: vite

So im trying to intgrate with June app, and it requires the env in the head tag which im trying to access from my env..
for Vue,  code snippet below [<%= %>] works fine, but for Vite, i keep getting POST 401 error but works fine when i expose the env without targeting my env file.;

````
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
   
    <script>
      window.analytics = {};
      function juneify(writeKey) {
        window.analytics._writeKey = writeKey;
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "application/javascript";
        script.onload = function () {
          window.analytics.page();
        };
        script.src =
          "https://unpkg.com/@june-so/analytics-next/dist/umd/standalone.js";
        var first = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        first.parentNode.insertBefore(script, first);
      }
      juneify("<%= import.meta.env.VITE_JUNEIFY_KEY %>");
    </script>
  </head>```


nothing i tried seems to work.
````

Comment: Apparently, I needed to update my vite project to v4.2.1 which now supports using <%%> in the head tag.